# How to filter a combobox dropdown list without filtering the store? is it possible?

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

I have two ComboBoxe's that use the same store. I want to filter the second combo with the select triggerAction on the first. If i filter the store of course it will be filtered for the first combo as well, and i don't want that so .. Is it possible to filter the dropdown list of an combobox without filtering the store? Thanks. If you can provide an example it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link the combo boxes this way... A selection in the first combobox is used as a parameter for the request in the second... once the parameter's value is set for the 2nd combobox's store, you can make an ajax call to your service to return the "filtered" data.

You'll need to use the store.reload() function to pull this off.

Comment: This is excellent. I need to get this working too ;-) may you share some code snippets with me?